# Не считываются данные из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

Задача:
Считать данные из файла, занести их в массив, провести действия с массивом, записать результат в выходной файл.

Использовал функцию `ifstream.gcount()` для подсчета количества символов. В выходной файл ничего не записывалось, но и сообщения об ошибке с открытием файла не возникало. Посмотрел под отладкой, обнаружил что `SIZE` остается со значением 0. В файле 9 значений, то есть ожидается что SIZE будет равняться 9. В чем здесь ошибка?

**Содержимое папки:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текстовые файлы находятся в одной папке с `main.cpp`

**input_data.txt:**

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream input_data;
    input_data.open("input_data.txt");

    if (!input_data.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    int SIZE = input_data.gcount();

    double** arr = new double* [SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = new double[SIZE];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            input_data >> arr[i][j];
    

    double max;

    max = (arr[0][0] > arr[1][0]) ? arr[0][0] : arr[1][0];
    max = (arr[0][0] > arr[2][0]) ? arr[0][0] : arr[2][0];
    max = (arr[1][0] > arr[2][0]) ? arr[1][0] : arr[2][0];

    ofstream output_file;
    output_file.open("output_data.txt");

    if (!output_file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                output_file << setprecision(3) << fixed << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            output_file << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gcount` возвращает количество символов, прочитаных последней операцией чтения, а не количество  символов в файле.

Comment: @EOF есть ли функция которая возвращает количество символов в файле? Или ее нужно в ручную прописывать?

Comment: Количество символов не равно количеству значений. Число 123.45 состоит из 6 символов, но это одно значение. Так как все значения записаны в одну строку, могу предложить сначала считывать все значение с файла и посчитать их, потом создать матрицу, перейти в начало файла и опять читать их, но уже в матрицу. Или писать их сразу в одномерный массив, который по необходимости увеличивать в размере и потом работать с ним как с матрицей.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream input_data;
    input_data.open("input_data.txt");

    if (!input_data.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error while opening file";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }


/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    int count = 0;

    while (!input_data.eof()) {
        char ch;
        while (input_data >> ch)
            count++;
    }

    int SIZE = sqrt(count);
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/

    double** arr = new double* [SIZE];
```

Comment: Как только у вас появятся не однозначные числа, все это работать перестанет... И, кстати, `while (!input_data.eof())` тут совсем не требуется.